# CDI events inheritance

Tags: events, java-ee-6, cdi

Is there a way of using class inheritance with CDI Events?

Lets say I have something like this:

```
public class ParentEvent{}

public class ChildEvent extends ParentEvent{}
```

and something like this:

```
public class Manager(){
    @Inject 
    private Event<ParrentEvent> event;

    public void foo(){
        event.fire(new ParentEvent());
    }

    public void bar(){
        event.fire(new ChildtEvent());
    }        
}

public class Observer{

      public void observesParent(@Observes ParentEvent event){
          //do something
      }

      public void observesChild(@Observes ChildEvent event){
          //do something
      }
}
```

In this case  both ParentEvent and ChildEvent are processed by observesParent() - due to type of event attribute in Manager class. Is there a way to observe ChildEvent with both observer methods?

Comment: I'd recommend your CDI Events be immutable and final to avoid any surprises. I'm not sure it would be a good idea to allow for behavior modification by anything, inheritance or otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of CDI is to use **qualifiers** in conjunction with events / observers (and not inheritance). Check [that chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/events.html) in the Weld documentation. The desired behaviour should be easily achievable with something like this:

```
public class Manager(){
    @Inject
    @Parent
    private Event<MyEvent> parentEvent;

    @Inject
    @Child
    private Event<MyEvent> childEvent; 

// ...

    public void foo(){
        event.fire(parentEvent);
    }

    public void bar(){
        event.fire(childEvent);
    }
}


public void observeChild(@Observes @Child MyEvent myEvent) { ... }
public void observeParent(@Observes @Parent MyEvent myEvent) { ... }
public void observeAll(@Observes MyEvent myEvent) { ... }
```

This far more flexible than using inheritance...

Comment: Main problem is that you cannot abstract observation (i mean the observer side) mecanism with qualified or generic events. Would be interrested to be able to do this, for example to provide some kind of framework used by your application business layer.